# Where should I ask questions about the Implementation of Zend Framework 2

Tags: support, questions

I'm not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question so forgive me if it isn't.

On Stack Overflow I asked what I thought was a reasonable question about the implementation decisions of ZF2 and I instantly got down voted.

Fair enough, but where is the best place to ask this type of question?

**update** I deleted the question because I didn't want to add to the clutter if the community had made a decision. It was basically a question as to why ZF2 hadn't implemented the Option class like they said here http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Zend+Framework+2.0+Roadmap

Comment: Can you show a link to the question?

Comment: sorry, I deleted the question because I didn't want to add to the clutter if the community had made a decision.

It was basically a question as to why ZF2 hadn't implemented the Option class like they said here http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Zend+Framework+2.0+Roadmap

Comment: I'm not sure that question would be a good fit anywhere. The answer would most likely be along the lines of "ask the developers".

Comment: I did ask the question on http://forums.zend.com, but it's like a ghost town and I didn't get a reply.

Comment: Even if the question was deleted, high rep users can still view it, so linking it is still a good idea.

Comment: But asking why something wasn't implemented probably isn't on-topic anywhere on stackexchange.

Comment: There wouldn't happen to be any Zend Developers on stackexchange at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have answered my question. I have found the [Zend Framework Community Forums](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Framework-Community-f634137.subapps.html) that seem to have implementation answers